# Document type association crashing the App when it's not running

Tags: swift, xcode, cfbundledocumenttypes

I have created my own **PDF Viewer** and want to associate the pdf file format with it so that i can open a pdf file from **Finder**, **Terminal** or with **Drag & Drop**. If I start the app and then try to open a pdf in one of the 3 ways mentioned before the document it's displayed correctly, but if i do the same thing when the App it's not open then it crashes.

Here my `CFBundleDocumentTypes` settings (from the **info.plist** file):

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>pdf</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>pdfformat</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>pdf</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Default</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>giannigianino.Mirror</string>
            </array>
            <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Here where the crash occur from the crash report:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   username.Mirror            0x0000000106a4d6e2 _T06Mirror11AppDelegateC11applicationSbSo13NSApplicationC_SS8openFiletF + 1090
1   username.Mirror            0x0000000106a4d749 _T06Mirror11AppDelegateC11applicationSbSo13NSApplicationC_SS8openFiletFTo + 89
2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9f355bd3 -[NSApplication _doOpenFile:ok:tryTemp:] + 322
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9f1407df -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _openDocumentURLs:withCompletionHandler:] + 996
```

I am also using a custom pdf icon but it's not displayed even if a set my App as the preferred one to open all pdf files.

Comment: Please do not post images of text. [Edit] your question and copy and paste relevant errors as text, not pictures. Same for any relevant code.

Comment: You are right, now it's more clean.

Comment: Now you need to post a symbolicated stack trace and the relevant code associated with the crash.

Comment: The strange thing is that this crash happen only when the app is not open, and nothing happen when it's already opened. So maybe this has nothing to do with the `openFile()` method call but with something to setup about the Launch Service.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. Basically the crash occur in the `application(_:openFile:)` method, where i was calling my `mainViewController` before it was instantiated. The solution was to move the code in the `applicationWillFinishLaunching(_:)` which is sent to the **Delegate** of the Application before the `application(_:openFile:)` and not in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:)` which is sent after.